# Enviar comando a mikrotik desde API con PHP

Tags: php, api

Hola quisiera que me ayudaran a crear un php que me mande una orden a mi mikrotik, el comando exacto que quiero que me ejecute dentro del mikrotik seria este:

> /user add name=api group=full password=api comment=userapi.

He intentado ya de varias formas pero el comando que tengo en php cuando lo ejecuto muestra en el mikrotik: user admin logged in from via api pero no me realiza el comando, 
El php que utilizo es este si alguien me pudiera ayudar le agradeceria

```
<?php

require('routeros_api.class.php');

$API = new RouterosAPI();

$API->debug = true;

if ($API->connect('192.168.7.3', 'admin', '123')) {

   $API->write('/user add name=api group=full password=api comment=usuario api');

   $READ = $API->read(false);
   $ARRAY = $API->parse_response($READ);

   print_r($ARRAY);

   $API->disconnect();

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en la forma en que estás pasando los parámetros. Primero tenés que escribir el comando, luego cada uno de los parámetros. Para esto la función **write** acepta un segundo argumento que te permite indicar que vas a mandar más información.

```
$API->write('/user add', false);
$API->write('name=api', false);
$API->write('group=full', false);
$API->write('password=api', false);
$API->write('comment={usuario api}', true);
```

Aunque, si querés simplificarte la vida, la api también trae una función llamada **comm** que te permite hacerlo así:

```
$API->comm('/user add', array(
    "name"     => "api",
    "group"    => "full",
    "password" => "api",
    "comment"  => "{usuario api}"
));
```

### Disclaimer

En mi vida toqué un mikrotik. La información la saqué de los ejemplos y comentarios del código que hay en el [repositorio de la API](https://github.com/BenMenking/routeros-api).

Comment: A esta bien muchas gracias intentaré hacerlo de esa manera

Answer (score 0):

> Hola Amigo puedes usar esto aver si te funciona

```
 $name="api";
 $group="full";
 $password="api"
 $comment="Usuario api";

$API->comm("/user/add", array(
    "name" => "$name",
    "group" => "$group",
    "password" => "$password",
    "comment" => "$comment",
  ));
```

> La verdad no estoy tan seguro si el Mikrotik te pide password y comment pero te deje arriba para que hagas la prueba si no te funciona puedes hacer con este codigo

```
$API->comm("/user/add", array(
    "name" => "$name",
    "group" => "$group",
  ));
```